# How do you insert links to a printed report?

Tags: paper-submission

I want to write something along the lines of:

```
For this I shall be using the foo library
```

And I wish to insert a link to said library, but I am confused as how to properly write the link. Do I insert it as a citation, a footnote, or just leave it there in the text?

Comment: References are references - they are not only for articles and books.

Comment: By library do you mean programming library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the library is important enough to be mentioned in the body of the article, I would definitely cite it.  (If it's only mentioned in a technical appendix, I *might* consider a footnote sufficient.)

Indeed, many software libraries or packages aimed at scientific use may carry a request that you do so, typically accompanied by an example citation, like this one from the [R programming language FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Citing-R):

> "To cite R in publications, use
>
> ```
> @Manual{,
>   title        = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
>   author       = {{R Core Team}},
>   organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
>   address      = {Vienna, Austria},
>   year         = 2013,
>   url          = {http://www.R-project.org}
> }
> ```
>
> Citation strings (or BibTeX entries) for R and R packages can also be obtained by `citation()`."

If no example citation format has been provided for your software library, I'd suggest citing the library web page in the same general fashion, e.g. as in:

> - The Foo Project. (2013). *The Foo Scientific Library*. v. 3.14.15. http://foo.org/fsl/

or as in:

> - Smith, J. (2011). "A fast frobnication routine for Intel CPUs". [http://example.edu/~jsmith/frob/](http://example.edu/%7Ejsmith/frob/)

If the library has been formally described in a published article or technical report, it may also be appropriate to cite the article or report instead.  In such cases, though, I would *usually* expect the library documentation to say so.

Ps. Here are a few earlier questions on the same or similar topics:

- [How do I reference the Python programming language in a thesis or a paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/how-do-i-reference-the-python-programming-language-in-a-thesis-or-a-paper)
- [How to cite software documentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/how-to-cite-software-documentation)
- [How to cite a website URL?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/how-to-cite-a-website-url)
- [How to cite a “product”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8948/how-to-cite-a-product)
- [How can I ensure that my software is correctly cited?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/how-can-i-ensure-that-my-software-is-correctly-cited)

Comment: As an addition: if the software/library is more like a product/tool than like a scientific work and doesn't specify a citation, I go for product-like specification, either in parenthesis or as footnote. E.g. "Spectra of hexane (Sigma-Aldrich, Munich, Germany, No. 296090) were acquired with a f/1.8 spectrograph (Kaiser Optical Systems, Ann Arbor MI, USA) and analyzed in Matlab (The Matworks, Natick MA, USA, Version 2007b) and R [1]". Citation for R as in the answer above. The "clash" of R and Matlab is a bit funny, but AFAIK Matlab doesn't have a citation like the official R book.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer footnote or in text. Others would also consider using a citation. Check your local style guide. Here is one possibility (http://lib.westfield.ma.edu/webapa.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In my area (management), links belong in the references section (whether on a separate references page or footnote depends on the citation format) but generally you should not put links in your text.

If there are referencing system which use in-text links, I have yet to see them.